# Can anybody identify this plant that looks like a Salvia?

Tags: identification, flowers

Can somebody help me identify this plant? It looks kind of like a salvia plant.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's one of the Veronicas, commonly known as Speedwell - I think its Veronica 'Royal Candles'. Picture in the link below, sorry its Amazon but it was the best one I could find...

[http://www.amazon.com/Royal-Candles-Veronica-Perennial-Speedwell/dp/B001TOTIC2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001TOTIC2)

Answer (score 1):

[Speedwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veronica_spicata) as it is commonly called can be found in almost any nursery around this time of the year in the united states. Depending on your zone it may not be offered or may be considered an Annual.

Its similar appearance to slavia makes it hard to differentiate for those who have never seen the plant before. The largest difference occurs in the family branch Salvia belonging to the [Lamiaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvia) and the [Speedwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veronica_spicata) belonging to the [Plantaginaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantaginaceae).

Being of the mint family the Salvia has a very fragrant nature. So now you know: if you're ever questioning yourself give it a sniff. The Speedwell will not have much of a fragrance, but the Salvia will!

Answer (score 0):

It is *Veronica spicata*.

Cheers,

RP

Comment: While correct, we already *had* this answer... I suggest you take the [tour] and especially visit the [help]  where it is [explained](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that a good answer should be "fleshed out" a bit. As it stands, it would be considered "low quality" by some.